# Which musical chords were forbidden by the Roman Catholic Church?

Tags: history

Is it true that during the middle ages there were some musical chords that were forbidden by the Roman Catholic Church? I heard somewhere that you would be even punished by the inquisition then for playing those chords in public. If that's true, I wonder what chords were they?

I've read a few articles on the history of European music, similar to this one:

https://www.brighthubeducation.com/history-homework-help/107326-evolution-of-music-during-the-middle-ages-and-renaissance/

but couldn't find any mention of forbidden chords.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean the [Tritone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritone) - I think tales that it was banned or involved the Spanish Inquisition are fanciful.
[BTW, the Inquisition mainly just gave people a verbal slap on the wrist; a few Hail Marys to say - their history is also often fanciful ;) Between them it makes for a good meme, but not really an accurate history.

There are two accounts of the Inquisition on Wikipedia, though one is disputed…
[Spanish Inquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Inquisition)
[Historical revision of the Inquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_revision_of_the_Inquisition)

Probably the best known example of the tritone - & certainly right there if your face without having to search for it - is the introduction to Jimi Hendrix's Purple Haze

Comment: I cite Black Sabbath off volume Black Sabbath by Black Sabbath for tritone.